# ISO Files Are Being Classified As Text Files Under Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, iso, dolphin, file-type

The ISO files that I have are not being detected properly by my Kubuntu system.

Some of them are getting detected as "**Raw CD Image**" but others getting  classified as "**Text Document**" or "**Windows Executable Program"**.

**Is there any way to fix this classification problem?**

[image]

**System Information:**

[image]

**Note:** I am using the Dolphin File Manager (**Dolphin 17.04.3**).

Comment: It seems to be a [known issue](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72643-32-bit-K-Ubuntu-ISOs-open-as-text-file-when-using-Dolphin?p=406937&viewfull=1#post406937).

Comment: By the way, what do you see when you run `find -iname "*.iso" -exec file {} +`?

Comment: It does not affect standard Ubuntu and the other Ubuntu flavours.

Comment: @DKBose : Thank you for your comments. I ran your suggested comment after navigating to the same directory shown in the image above. The result was as follows:

./slitaz-rolling.iso:  DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 2 : ID=0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 172, 8020 sectors

./tails-amd64-3.5.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x17, active, start-CHS (0x0,0,1), end-CHS (0x93,254,63), startsector 0, 2377620 sectors

Comment: @sudodus : Thank you for your comment. It is not affecting other Ubuntu flavors indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are sure that those are iso files, and you know where you got them from, mount them and check out for errors.

sudo mkdir /media/iso0

sudo mkdir /media/iso1

sudo mount -o loop path/to/iso/file/YOUR_ISO_FILE0.ISO /media/iso0

sudo mount -o loop path/to/iso/file/YOUR_ISO_FILE1.ISO /media/iso1

if you got no errors then those are iso files, check what's inside them in the folder /media/iso0 and /media/iso1

if there are errors, Kubuntu is right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Those ISO files are Linux operating systems that I have downloaded from their official websites. I have checked them and confirmed that they are indeed ISO files. However, Kubuntu through the Dolphin file manager is not able to group them or classify them properly. This problem is affecting all of my ISO files, not just the above two.